# What is the difference between MULTICAST and ALLMULTI ifconfig ifconfig flags

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

What is the precise difference between the `ifconfig` flags `MULTICAST` and `ALLMULTI`?

Also How do I change the default flags under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

In Linux the driver has three multicast operating modes.

- Multicast can be disabled.
- It can be enabled, IFF_MULTICAST.  The driver looks at multicast packets to see if they match *dev->mc_list which is a list of currently configured multicast addresses (usually managed by the applications that need the group).
- Then the last mode, IFF_ALLMULTI.  In this mode the driver forwards all multicast packets to the kernel for handling.  This is commonly used for routing since you don't usually want the router to be a client of the stream/group but a courier for it.  Here is some more information on the internals of that:

http://www.makelinux.com/ldd3/chp-17-sect-14#chp-17-sect-14.1

In Ubuntu you use ifconfig:

```
 # ifconfig eth0 allmulti
```

Comment: I am using avahi on ubintu in vmware. After I installed VMWARE tools the ethernet driver changed to vmxnet2 and I had to enable ALLMULTI to browse with avahi. Very weird.